# PHP regex to match groups in string

Tags: php, regex, routes

i have a PHP project that uses routing this passes the url requested `feedback/services/mytoken` i then have a regex that detects the parts o pass to the script with this `/^feedback(\/(?P<form>.*))(\/(?P<token>.*))/U` example [RegEx Test](https://regex101.com/r/V7oSKn/2) this works fine for now, but i have realized that i will come into some issues when the url is `feedback/service` it wont pick it up.

```php
// working
$request = 'feedback/services/mytoken';
$regex = '/^feedback(\/(?P<form>.*))(\/(?P<token>.*))/U';
// returns
$returns = [
"form" => 'services',
"token" => "mytoken" 

];

// not working
$request = 'feedback/services';
$regex = '/^feedback(\/(?P<form>.*))(\/(?P<token>.*))/U';
// expected returns
$returns = [
"form" => 'services'
];
```

i want to be able to capture the groups correctly but i'm not sure of the right way to go about it. also i want to be able to pick it up if only part of it matches i.e. `feedback/services` is sent, it will group form to services and not match token

Comment: Use `'~^feedback(?:/(?P<form>[^/]*))?(?:/(?P<token>[^/]*))?~'`

Comment: I would use this `feedback\/?(?P<form>[^\/]*)?\/?(?P<token>[^\/]*)?`  [Sandbox](https://regex101.com/r/V7oSKn/7)  This removes some spurious capture groups (IMO) and gets rid of the slashes in the matches.  You could remove  `?`  from the first `\/?` to make that `/` required as in `feedback/`  as you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
'~^feedback(?:/(?P<form>[^/]*))?(?:/(?P<token>[^/]*))?~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GNQJgR/1)

If no more text should appear on the right, add `$` at the end of the regex:

```
'~^feedback(?:/(?P<form>[^/]*))?(?:/(?P<token>[^/]*))?$~'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of input
- `feedback` - literal string
- `(?:/(?P<form>[^/]*))?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `/` - a `/` char  (no need to escape since `~` is used a regex delimiter char)
  - `(?P<form>[^/]*)` - Group "form": any 0 or more chars other than `/`
- `(?:/(?P<token>[^/]*))?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `(?P<token>[^/]*)` - Group "token": any 0 or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of input.